# Sqoop unload from oracle table while the table is getting loaded

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am able to unload data from oracle data base using `sqoop`. But some times my job kicks off while the upstream load is going on. I don't have dependency set up as the upstream jobs are out side my environment.

**Sqoop query:**

```
select * from PFSIEBEL.'${TBL_NM}' where trunc(last_upd) >=(to_char(to_date('${ODATE}','YYYYMMDD')))
```

This is the query I am using the pull delta records from the table.

I would like to know what sqoop does while pulling data from rdbms ?
 What happens when transaction is going on the records in RDBMS ?

Comment: I don't know Sqoop, but presumably it's the same as for any other SQL query, i.e. you only see data as it existed at the start of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop doesnt do  dirty read means doesnt import data which is yet not committed and are being modified. 
--relaxed-isolation option can be used to instruct Sqoop to use read uncommitted isolation level.

but it doesnt support for oracle.